# Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [over] with [class io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver]

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, automated-tests, testng

Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [over] with [class io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver].

getting this error

[image: Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [over] with [class io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver].]

TestNG.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test   verbose="2" preserve-order="true" thread-count="5" name="Test">
  
  
   <classes>
            <class name="Apps.Utilshelper">
               
            </class>

            <class name="Apps.SGH">
                <methods>
                    <include name="Capabilities"/>
                    
                </methods>
                  </class>
                  
                  <class name="Apps.Overview">
                <methods>
                    <include name="over"/>
                    
                </methods>
                  </class>
            
            
            
            
              </classes>
            
  
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

can anyone help it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You marked your class with `@Test` annotation which made all the methods in the class to be test methods.

You cannot just define any parameter within your test method. You have to deal with injection mechanism.

- Either to use [dependency injection](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods) mechanism that would inject some internal TestNG objects so that you could have access to the execution context, and so on (btw your error message suggests you to visit the URL for that topic)
- Or use [parameter providers](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters) that would supply your test methods with the parameter values for each run.

If you have that method just as utility one that has not be executed as a test, then either use per-test annotation approach (so that you have only real tests annotated) or take that method to different class.

Comment: Building on this, I noticed that when using kotlin the auto-generated get/set methods were then considered test methods, and understandably would not work. In my case I was able to remove the `@Test` annotation as it was only an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error in my code. Changing the method from public to private worked for me.